# To solve the matrix equation

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

Suppose, I have a matrix equation $H(A) = K$, where $K$, $A$, and $H(A)$ are non-singular, real matrices. $H(A)$ is some function of $A$, for example $H(A) = A^2 + A^3$. Will I always get a solution for $A$ from this equation, for any possible $H$? If not, a counter example will be really helpful.

**Update:** As @Sobi commented, now I know that this equation does not hold in general. So my updated question is, under which (minimal) conditions, if there is some, I will have a solution? I think if $H$ is a linear operation, then there probably exists a solution. What can be other conditions instead of this; maybe like $H$ and $K$ need to be positive definite or something.

Comment: What if $H(A) = BA$ where $B$ is a constant non-invertible matrix?

Comment: I am assuming $H(A)$ to be non-singular.

Comment: Missed that, sorry!

Comment: Then how about the $1 \times 1$ case where $K = -1$ and $H(A) = A^2$. Then you are looking for a real solution to $A^2 = -1$, which does not exist.

Comment: @Sobi could you kindly tell me under which (minimal) conditions, if there is some, I will have a solution?

Comment: I really cannot tell since I am not an expert in this area. Although, I found [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379512006441) that might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

One sufficient condition for example is that $K$ be diagonalizable with eigenvalues in the range of the analytic function $H: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. For example with $H(x)=x^2+x^3$, the range is all real numbers, so $H(A)=K$ has a solution for any diagonalizable $K$. If $K=PDP^{-1}$, let $D=(d_1,\ldots, d_n)$ and let $E=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ such that $H(a_i)=d_i$ for all $1\leq i \leq n$. Then $A=P EP^{-1}$ is a solution of $H(A)=K$.